# Android: Signing for many customers (MonoDroid)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, keystore, signing

We have 3 different customers whom we will be building Android apps for.

Using the Java SDK tool, **keytool**, we generate 3 different keystore files.

Do we use the same KeyStore file to sign every app for each company, or does each app need its own keystore?

See: http://android.xamarin.com/Documentation/Guides/Preparing_Package_for_Android_Marketplace?highlight=market

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single keystore file can contain many keys.  Each key within the keystore has an alias (ie name), that you use when signing with that key.  You can put all three keys for each application into a single keystore without a problem.

You can use a single key for all applications, but if that key is compromised you'll need to change the key affecting all applications.  Normally key compromise isn't that likely a risk, but if you have contractors working on each application it limits you from having a contractor running away with the key or something like that.

Comment: I don't see there being much reason why contractors or even most employees should have access to the production keys.  Presumably you have some in-house qualification hoops code has to jump through before being formally published; when it's passed, someone key to your android efforts can re-sign it with the real keys, which should probably be on only one active machine (though backed up offline).

Comment: Sure.  That is how every place should operate, but we all know that's not reality.  Most of the time small shops don't even know these keys exist because the developer just took care of it for them.  Plus people loose their password, machines crash, etc.  My only point was if you tie them all together changes to it will affect all apps instead of just one.  Use that information however you desire.

Answer (score 1):

The key signing is to identify the developer not the customer, [the Android Market documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) suggests this. If you need to use separate keys you can use one keystore with more than one signature or one per keystore. I would suggest you have one keystore file per Android Market account. Although you don't say if these apps are posted on the Market. Keytool will allow you to import and export signatures giving you some flexibility here.

Answer (score 0):

Keys is to sign digitaly your Application ... So it identify the publisher

Publisher keys : Digitaly final release application for end customer usage

Worker developper keys : 1 years validity easy generated by eclipse (with ADT)

So if your issue is : One publisher 3 workers ... Single publisher Key pair is enough
If you do not want to give the private key to the worker ...

!! In Fact publisher do not have to provide publisher private keys to workers

--> workers only need development key autogenerated by eclipse with a 1 years validity
that can be regenerated I many time you want but not for publishing usage

-->Publisher will take the final APK application (provided by workers) files unsigned then Publisher will signed/zipalign these APK into new APK to provide "as is" to final customer or upload into a market store.

Comment: NB: The date time validity is just for installation ... after installation if the key is not valid the application still be executable.. But can't be installed anymore...